# Edge labels in GraphPlot3D from Adjacency Matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks, graphics3d

I am rendering a family of graphs via `GraphPlot3D[AdjacencyMatrix]` and I would also like to label the edges. I already use a vertex rendering function to color the vertices.

There are two ways to do this that I'm aware of:

- `EdgeLabels -> [Array]`
- `EdgeRenderingFunction -> {Function}`

Is there a simpler way to label the edges, analogous to the "manual" method:

```
GraphPlot3D[edge -> "label"]
```

Comment: Could you introduce your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjacency matrix:

```
am = {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
sa = SparseArray @ am;
```

Label matrix:

```
lm = RandomChoice[DictionaryLookup[x__ /; StringLength[x] == 3][[ ;; 100]], {4, 4}];
```

Construct edges annotated with labels using the matrices `am` and `lm`:

```
elist = Property[Rule @@ #, EdgeLabels -> lm[[## & @@ #]]] & /@ sa["NonzeroPositions"];
```

Use `Graph3D`

```
g1 = Graph3D[elist, EdgeLabelStyle -> 20, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

If you wish you can use the vertex coordinates used by `GraphPlot3D`:

```
SetProperty[g1, VertexCoordinates -> GraphPlot3D[am][[1, 1, 1]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `GraphPlot3D` with a custom `EdgeRenderingFunction`:

```
erf = {RGBColor[.5, 0, 0], Line[#], Text[lm[[## & @@ #2]], (#1[[1]] + #1[[2]])/2, 
     Background -> White]} &;

GraphPlot3D[am, EdgeRenderingFunction -> erf]
```

[image]